# node js can't install right on my Ubuntu computer

Tags: node.js

I use the git to install node js, the method I use is below:

```
mkdir ~/local
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc

git clone git://github.com/joyent/node.git
cd node
./configure --prefix=~/local
make install
cd ..
```

After this, I use node on my command line, it tell me no node.Any one can help me?
I got the method form https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814, but can't work.
My path is here. 
[image: my $PATH]

Answer (score 3):

You have to `make` before you `make install`.

[The wiki has more information about building from source.](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation#building-on-gnulinux-and-other-unix)

Comment: But after that, I also find some questions. Things like this,npm install -g supervisor,the command line tell me that " Acess error",so I change the owner and permission of the fold to npm install!

Comment: @sgsheg: You have to `sudo` when you `npm install -g` (but not for regular -- without `-g` -- installs).

Comment: to make it easy, on my computer,I change the permission!

Answer (score 1):

I used NVM to install Node.js to my Ubuntu computer:

First install these packages

```
sudo apt-get install curl build-essential libssl-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libexpat1-dev
```

Install nvm

```
git clone https://github.com/creationix/nvm.git ~/.nvm
```

To activate nvm, you need to source it from your bash shell (e.g, add to your ~/.bash_profile)

```
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

The following steps are also required when upgrading Node

Install Node (use whichever version you like, but v0.8.x works)

```
nvm install v0.8.23

nvm alias default v0.8.23

nvm use v0.8.23
```

Any issues, I would check out the [NVM repo](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

Comment: Thanks, I will try it on another computer.

Answer (score 0):

This is my build script for node.js on ubuntu. I don't build from the bleeding edge most recent code, but its close to your process.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential libssl-dev

wget http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/
node_version=`grep -i 'current version' index.html | sed -E 's/.*([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*/\1/'`
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v$node_version/node-v$node_version.tar.gz
tar -xzf node-v$node_version.tar.gz
cd node-v$node_version
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd ..
rm -rf node-v$node_version.tar.gz node-v$node_version index.html
```

Comment: FYI... The wiki https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation#building-on-gnulinux-and-other-unix says  that libssl-dev is only needed in 0.6.x, but I get errors running ./configure even with 0.8.x and 0.10.x if I omit the libssl-dev install