# nodejs can't send request to remote https server

Tags: node.js, https, nginx

I have a Nodejs app on Amazon EC2 instance, and the nodejs app is listening port 2000.

This is Nodejs snippet,

```
var request = require('request');
request('https:[host]',{},function(err,res,body){
    console.log(res,body);
})
```

Requesting with http is ok, but with https it only got 'undefined'. 
But CLI `curl -k ' https:[host] ' works on the same instance.

What is the problem? Thanks

This is Nginx conf

```
upstream nodeserver {
    server 127.0.0.1:2000;
}

server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/nodeserver.log;

    location / {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://nodeserver;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

This is security group:

```
Port (Service)  Source  
22 (SSH)    0.0.0.0/0   
80 (HTTP)   0.0.0.0/0   
443 (HTTPS) 0.0.0.0/0       
2000    127.0.0.1/32
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile from source? If openssl libs were not available at the ./configure step of compiling, node will not be able to connect to any SSL end-point.

See this post for info on compiling node: [node js can't install right on my Ubuntu computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153163/node-js-cant-install-right-on-my-ubuntu-computer/18155091#18155091)