# NVM and Module version mismatch

Tags: node.js, nvm

I installed NVM to manage Nodejs versions. I have checked out a software which needs 0.8.18, so I installed it through NVM and `use`d it (`nvm use 0.8.18`). Now, I recompiled all the modules, but I keep receiving the message `Error: Module version mismatch, refusing to load.`.

Am I missing some steps? Thanks

Comment: How did you compile modules? I guess it's linking to different version of node. Try to set path manually to your node version

Comment: I just uninstalled and re-installed them. How can I manually set the path to the node distribution in the NVM folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
nvm install v0.8.18

nvm alias default v0.8.18

nvm use v0.8.18
```

Comment: Thanks for the shot, unfortunately that is not working either

Comment: What OS are you using? And do you have more specifics from your error message? [See if this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584529/module-version-mismatch-expected-11-got-1)

Comment: I'm running under Ubuntu 12.04 and unfortunately I have no more specific message. In the end I removed both `NVM` and `nodejs` and directly cloned the Node version I needed from git.

Comment: That's the same OS I use. So you got it working correctly? I found using NVM to install Node.js was fairly simple. I would check out this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153163/node-js-cant-install-right-on-my-ubuntu-computer/18156947#18156947) if you're going to try NVM again.